# SQL Server Configuration in LAN by ADSL Router

Tags: sql-server, router, port-forwarding

I have a LAN which I connect two PCs through an ADSL Router.

I want to disable the internet on the PC carrying the SQL Server, and of course want to still be able to connect to SQL Server from the other PC.

**My Configuration:**

1. To block the internet from the server, I set its gateway to nothing.
2. To enable access, I added the ports (TCP 1433, UDP 1434) to the firewall exceptions list on the server.
3. I am connecting to the server from my client using SSMS's normal connect.

There are some blogs on the internet which say I have to 4. forward the same two ports to my server IP on my router settings, Is this last step necessary? because after applying the above 3 steps, I already can connect from my client.

Or the port forwarding step is meant only for VPN configuration (which I don't need I guess)?

Comment: Without knowing which router you have, thus not having someone be able to step you through the screens, this is as simple as NOT giving your SQL server box a NATed address on the router.  That being said, how do you ever propose to update this box?

Comment: @GregD Did you hear me asking for screens or snapshots? my question is specific to the 4th step.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to set up port forwarding on the router to connect to the SQL Server from the same LAN. You would only set up port forwarding on the router if you wanted to connect to SQL Server from the internet.